# Error commande mvn from console Intellij and java 11

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-11

I have a problem with command mvn

I work with Intellij and java 11

I clone a project and when i tape a command on terminal, he doesn't work.

For exemple :
mvn test -> on console : error
with maven tab : its ok

My stacktrace :

```
brichet@brichet-G11CD:~/IdeaProjects/cours_TDD/oc-testing-java-cours$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon$__sisu21
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.<init> (ProtocolVersion.java:158)
at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.<clinit> (ProtocolVersion.java:41)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit> (SSLContextImpl.java:560)

....

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error in security property. Constraint unknown:
jdk.disabled.namedCurves
at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$Constraints.<init>
(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:329)
at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.<init>
(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:100)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmConstraints.<clinit> (SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java:45)
at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.<init> (ProtocolVersion.java:158)
at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.<clinit> (ProtocolVersion.java:41)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit> (SSLContextImpl.java:560)
at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:315)
at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass (Provider.java:1848)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance (Provider.java:1824)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance (GetInstance.java:236)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance (GetInstance.java:164)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance (SSLContext.java:168)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault (SSLContext.java:99)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault (SSLSocketFactory.java:123)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory
(HttpsURLConnection.java:335)
at
 .......
---------------------------------------------------

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error in security property. Constraint unknown:
jdk.disabled.namedCurvesat
java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$Constraints.<init>(DisabledAlgorithmCo
nstraints.java:329)
at
java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.<init>(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java
:100)
at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmConstraints.<clinit>(SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java:45)
... 84 more
```

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 0):

May be check maven JDK version and intellij project JDK version (on the Projet Structure / Project Settings / Projet SDK menu)  , it may have a difference